# How to read.csv a column as logical and not as character?

Tags: r, csv

Into a csv file I have a column which contains logical operator values TRUE, FALSE.

When I use read.csv as following

it reads the column as character. How can I modify read.csv() to read it as logi?

I use this option of read as I have multiple csv files

```
files <- list.files(path = "C/path/files",pattern = ".csv")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
dframe <- rbindlist( temp )
```

Comment: There's no `read.csv` in your code. `fread` is not a base function... not sure what it does. `colClasses` argument to `read.csv` may be the right thing here.

Comment: @cory fread is a fast alternative to read.csv from data.table. I agree that OP should show any libraries she loaded for her current code.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `colClasses` argument of the `read.csv` function. Provide a character vector of classes for the columns in your data set.

From the help page of `read.csv`:

> **colClasses** character. A vector of classes to be assumed for the
>   columns...